# CSS to float copy to the right

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I've created the following:

[image: My display]

And I'd like the top section 'independent' to be over to the right like the 'interactive' section. I've tried to float: right; but that's not correct.

My code is:

```
.badgesblock{style: 'padding-left: 30px;'}
  .independent
    = image_tag 'independent.png', style: 'float:left;'
    .independentcopy{style: ''}
      %p{style: 'font-weight: bold;'} Independent
      %p{style: 'width: 450px;'} We’re the only independent user review site for wedding suppliers. Businesses can’t vet reviews on their listing – that’s why your customers trust us.
  %br
  %br
  .verified
    = image_tag 'verified.png', style: 'float:right;'
    %p{style: 'font-weight: bold;'} Verified
    %p{style: 'width: 450px;'} All reviews and reviewers are verified. Each user fills in their personal details and verifies their profile with a wedding date and a picture. The result is an authentic, trustworthy review system.
  %br
  %br
  .interactive
    = image_tag 'interactive.png', style: 'float:left;'
    .interactivecopy{style: 'float:right;'}
      %p{style: 'font-weight: bold;'} Interactive
      %p{style: 'width: 450px;'} Passive display advertising has limited impact. We provide a unique opportunity to actively engage with potential customers and showcase the great service at the heart of your business.
```

What am I missing in the CSS?

Comment: You've answered your own question. Use the exact css you've used for your `.interactive` class and you should be fine. However, you shouldn't use css in html.

Comment: When I put float: right in it doesn't work. Is that what you mean?

Comment: (I'll move the css out. Good point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty clear cut case for a piece of reusable CSS called [the media object](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/).

Its a basic building block with an image, video or whatever and associated text on the left or right.

```css
/** Generic media object **/
.media {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.media-item {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.media.flipped > .media-item {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 25px;
  float: right;
}

/** specific styles **/
.badge {
   /* ... */
}
```

```html
<div class="badgesblock">
  <div class="media badge independent">
    <a href="#" class="media-item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150"/>
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
      <p><strong>Independent</strong></p>
      <p>We’re the only independent user review site for wedding suppliers. Businesses can’t vet reviews on their listing – that’s why your customers trust us.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="media badge flipped verified">
    <a href="#" class="media-item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" />
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
      <p><strong>Verified</strong></p>
      <p>All reviews and reviewers are verified. Each user fills in their personal details and verifies their profile with a wedding date and a picture. The result is an authentic, trustworthy review system.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="media badge interactive">
    <a href="#" class="media-item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" />
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
      <p><strong>Interactive</strong></p>
      <p>Passive display advertising has limited impact. We provide a unique opportunity to actively engage with potential customers and showcase the great service at the heart of your business.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
h2, p {
  margin: 0;
}

.section {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.section:nth-child(odd) img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.section:nth-child(even) img {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="badgesblock">
  <div class="section independent">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div class="independentCopy">
      <h2>Independent</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae mollitia voluptates est, porro dolor suscipit perspiciatis asperiores, dolorum dicta vel sunt, cupiditate, animi reiciendis quis similique fugiat. Vel, ut, dolore.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section verified">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div class="verifiedCopy">
      <h2>Verified</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae mollitia voluptates est, porro dolor suscipit perspiciatis asperiores, dolorum dicta vel sunt, cupiditate, animi reiciendis quis similique fugiat. Vel, ut, dolore.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section interactive">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    <div class="interactiveCopy">
      <h2>Interactive</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae mollitia voluptates est, porro dolor suscipit perspiciatis asperiores, dolorum dicta vel sunt, cupiditate, animi reiciendis quis similique fugiat. Vel, ut, dolore.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You don't have to do it like I did. I'm using some new (to you) css selectors like nth-child which makes it easier for me. But if you want to target by class or whatever, feel free. I just gave you an idea of what kind of css you need to achieve what you want.

Think of `.section:nth-child(odd)` like:

    `.section.independent img,
    .section.interactive img { }`

http://codepen.io/pacMakaveli/pen/jPEegN

Comment: You mind editing your question so that the html is not just one huge line?